# java openCV Core.inRange Input Parameters

Tags: java, opencv

```
Core.inRange(frame, new Scalar(minA,minB,minC), new Scalar(maxA,maxB,maxC), dst);
```

I do not understand which parameter should I enter to Scalar.
and how can I convert RGB to it. (I am using openCV 2.412).
according to http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.12/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html?highlight=scalar
the parameter should be BGR, but it haven't achieved the desired result.

Input:

```
Core.inRange(frame, new Scalar(0,0,0), new Scalar(0,0,255), dst);
```

Input Picture:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *red* rectangle has value `(0,0,240)`, so you can use:

```
inRange(img, new Scalar(0, 0, 230), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), dst);
```

The *green* rectangle has value `(0,240,0)`, so you can use:

```
inRange(img, new Scalar(0, 230, 0), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), dst);
```

The *blue* rectangle has value `(240,0,0)`, so you can use:

```
inRange(img, new Scalar(230, 0, 0), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), dst);
```

The *gray* rectangle has value `(100,100,100)`, so you can use:

```
inRange(img, new Scalar(90, 90, 90), new Scalar(110, 110, 110), dst);
```

---

Finding all rectangles at once can be tricky. It's better to first detect the black `(0,0,0)` background, and then invert the mask:

```
inRange(img, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), new Scalar(10, 10, 10), dst);
bitwise_not(dst, dst);
```